# Flask url_for not playing video

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm working on a flask website, and I'm analyzing a video, and want to show it on the web page. But when I tried putting direct path to the video source, but it showed black screen. And when I looked up on google they suggested me to use url_for, but that too didn't work...

Here's my code
Assume that I've imported flask and also imported the url_for method
and I've created the static folder...

```
@app.route("/show", method=["GET","POST"]) 
def show():
    return f"""<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Video Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
        <source src="{url_for('static', filename='t.mp4')}" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    </body>
    </html>"""
```

It is just showing the black player screen...

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i got the answer, the mistake was I didn't put double quote on the src attribute. And one more thing I did was, I found a piece of code which I pasted and It works...

I did these changes:

`app=Flask(__name__, static_folder='static'`

```
@app.route("/show", method=["GET","POST"]) 
def show():
    return f"""<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Video Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
        <source src="{url_for('static', filename='t.mp4')}" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    </body>
    </html>"""
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file inside static folder than it should follow as and you can give height and width in video according to your requirement!

```
<video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
    <source src={{url_for('static', filename="t.mp4")}} type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

since you are not using `render_template()` function but an `f-string` to render the template string then you are using the right sytax but the only thing you need is to make sure you import `url_for` function so it then can be evaluated as an expression by `f-string` and it should work:

```py
from flask import Flask, url_for
```

refer to https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python

Comment: first I tried using 2 curly brackets but then I changed it to single one to see if there are any changes

Comment: But thanks I'll again try this if it works

Comment: I didn't work for me still getting same... Thanks BTW

Comment: Broo read my question carefully I've imported it

Comment: I think I know how to fix it, because the src attribute is not having double quote. Is this the problem